# Sympify changes order of everything

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following symbols in my Sympy script

```
e0 = Symbol('e0',commutative=False)
e1 = Symbol('e1',commutative=False)
e2 = Symbol('e2',commutative=False)
e3 = Symbol('e3',commutative=False)

u = Symbol('u',commutative=False)

d0 = Symbol('d0',commutative=False)
d1 = Symbol('d1',commutative=False)
d2 = Symbol('d2',commutative=False)
d3 = Symbol('d3',commutative=False)


A_0 = (Symbol('a_00',commutative=False),Symbol('a_01',commutative=False),Symbol('a_02',commutative=False),Symbol('a_03',commutative=False))
A_1 = symbols('a_10:14',commutative=False)
A_2 = symbols('a_20:24',commutative=False)
A_3 = symbols('a_30:34',commutative=False)

B = symbols('b_0:4',commutative=False)

C = Symbol('C',commutative=False)
```

And I have a really big string:

```
e0*((d0*a_00)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_00*(-e1*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)-e2*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)-e3*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u))) + e1*((d0*a_01)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_01*(-e1*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)-e2*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)-e3*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u))) + e2*((d0*a_02)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_02*(-e1*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)-e2*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)-e3*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u))) + e3*((d0*a_03)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_03*(-e1*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)-e2*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)-e3*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u))) + e0*((d0*a_10)*(d1*u)+a_10*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e1*((d0*a_11)*(d1*u)+a_11*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e2*((d0*a_12)*(d1*u)+a_12*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e3*((d0*a_13)*(d1*u)+a_13*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e0*((d0*a_20)*(d2*u)+a_20*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e1*((d0*a_21)*(d2*u)+a_21*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e2*((d0*a_22)*(d2*u)+a_22*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e3*((d0*a_23)*(d2*u)+a_23*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e0*((d0*a_30)*(d3*u)+a_30*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e1*((d0*a_31)*(d3*u)+a_31*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e2*((d0*a_32)*(d3*u)+a_32*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e3*((d0*a_33)*(d3*u)+a_33*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e0*((d0*b_0)*u+b_0*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)) + e1*((d0*b_1)*u+b_1*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)) + e2*((d0*b_2)*u+b_2*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)) + e3*((d0*b_3)*u+b_3*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)) + e_1*((d1*a_00)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_00*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + -e0*((d1*a_01)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_01*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e3*((d1*a_02)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_02*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + -e2*((d1*a_03)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_03*(-e1*d1*d1*u-e2*d1*d2*u-e3*d1*d3*u)) + e_1*((d1*a_10)*(d1*u)+a_10*(d1*d1*u)) + -e0*((d1*a_11)*(d1*u)+a_11*(d1*d1*u)) + e3*((d1*a_12)*(d1*u)+a_12*(d1*d1*u)) + -e2*((d1*a_13)*(d1*u)+a_13*(d1*d1*u)) + e_1*((d1*a_20)*(d2*u)+a_20*(d1*d2*u)) + -e0*((d1*a_21)*(d2*u)+a_21*(d1*d2*u)) + e3*((d1*a_22)*(d2*u)+a_22*(d1*d2*u)) + -e2*((d1*a_23)*(d2*u)+a_23*(d1*d2*u)) + e_1*((d1*a_30)*(d3*u)+a_30*(d1*d3*u)) + -e0*((d1*a_31)*(d3*u)+a_31*(d1*d3*u)) + e3*((d1*a_32)*(d3*u)+a_32*(d1*d3*u)) + -e2*((d1*a_33)*(d3*u)+a_33*(d1*d3*u)) + e_1*((d1*b_0)*u+b_0*(d1*u)) + -e0*((d1*b_1)*u+b_1*(d1*u)) + e3*((d1*b_2)*u+b_2*(d1*u)) + -e2*((d1*b_3)*u+b_3*(d1*u)) + e2*((d2*a_00)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_00*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + -e3*((d2*a_01)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_01*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + -e0*((d2*a_02)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_02*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e1*((d2*a_03)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_03*(-e1*d2*d1*u-e2*d2*d2*u-e3*d2*d3*u)) + e2*((d2*a_10)*(d1*u)+a_10*(d2*d1*u)) + -e3*((d2*a_11)*(d1*u)+a_11*(d2*d1*u)) + -e0*((d2*a_12)*(d1*u)+a_12*(d2*d1*u)) + e1*((d2*a_13)*(d1*u)+a_13*(d2*d1*u)) + e2*((d2*a_20)*(d2*u)+a_20*(d2*d2*u)) + -e3*((d2*a_21)*(d2*u)+a_21*(d2*d2*u)) + -e0*((d2*a_22)*(d2*u)+a_22*(d2*d2*u)) + e1*((d2*a_23)*(d2*u)+a_23*(d2*d2*u)) + e2*((d2*a_30)*(d3*u)+a_30*(d2*d3*u)) + -e3*((d2*a_31)*(d3*u)+a_31*(d2*d3*u)) + -e0*((d2*a_32)*(d3*u)+a_32*(d2*d3*u)) + e1*((d2*a_33)*(d3*u)+a_33*(d2*d3*u)) + e2*((d2*b_0)*u+b_0*(d2*u)) + -e3*((d2*b_1)*u+b_1*(d2*u)) + -e0*((d2*b_2)*u+b_2*(d2*u)) + e1*((d2*b_3)*u+b_3*(d2*u)) + e3*((d3*a_00)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_00*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e2*((d3*a_01)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_01*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + -e1*((d3*a_02)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_02*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + -e0*((d3*a_03)*(-e1*d1*u-e2*d2*u-e3*d3*u)+a_03*(-e1*d3*d1*u-e2*d3*d2*u-e3*d3*d3*u)) + e3*((d3*a_10)*(d1*u)+a_10*(d3*d1*u)) + e2*((d3*a_11)*(d1*u)+a_11*(d3*d1*u)) + -e1*((d3*a_12)*(d1*u)+a_12*(d3*d1*u)) + -e0*((d3*a_13)*(d1*u)+a_13*(d3*d1*u)) + e3*((d3*a_20)*(d2*u)+a_20*(d3*d2*u)) + e2*((d3*a_21)*(d2*u)+a_21*(d3*d2*u)) + -e1*((d3*a_22)*(d2*u)+a_22*(d3*d2*u)) + -e0*((d3*a_23)*(d2*u)+a_23*(d3*d2*u)) + e3*((d3*a_30)*(d3*u)+a_30*(d3*d3*u)) + e2*((d3*a_31)*(d3*u)+a_31*(d3*d3*u)) + -e1*((d3*a_32)*(d3*u)+a_32*(d3*d3*u)) + -e0*((d3*a_33)*(d3*u)+a_33*(d3*d3*u)) + e3*((d3*b_0)*u+b_0*(d3*u)) + e2*((d3*b_1)*u+b_1*(d3*u)) + -e1*((d3*b_2)*u+b_2*(d3*u)) + -e0*((d3*b_3)*u+b_3*(d3*u))
```

This is what I do to sympify it:

```
ns={"e0":e0,"e1":e1,"e2":e2,"e3":e3,"u":u,"d0":d0,"d1":d1,"d2":d2,"d3":d3,"a_00":A_0[0],"a_01":A_0[1],"a_02":A_0[2],"a_03":A_0[3],"a_10":A_1[0],"a_11":A_1[1],"a_12":A_1[2],"a_13":A_1[3],"a_20":A_2[0],"a_21":A_2[1],"a_22":A_2[2],"a_23":A_2[3],"a_30":A_3[0],"a_31":A_3[1],"a_32":A_3[2],"a_33":A_3[3]}
print(sympify(result,locals=ns,evaluate=False))
```

and the result is very different from what I had:

```
e_1*(a_00*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d1*a_00*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e_1*(d1*b_0*u + b_0*d1*u) + e_1*(a_10*d1*d1*u + d1*a_10*d1*u) + e_1*(a_20*d1*d2*u + d1*a_20*d2*u) + e_1*(a_30*d1*d3*u + d1*a_30*d3*u) + e0*(a_00*(-e2*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) - e3*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + (d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u)*(-e1)) + d0*a_00*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e0*(a_10*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d0*a_10*d1*u) + e0*(a_20*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d0*a_20*d2*u) + e0*(a_30*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d0*a_30*d3*u) + e0*(d0*b_0*u + b_0*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e1*(a_01*(-e2*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) - e3*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + (d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u)*(-e1)) + d0*a_01*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e1*(a_03*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d2*a_03*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e1*(a_11*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d0*a_11*d1*u) + e1*(a_21*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d0*a_21*d2*u) + e1*(a_31*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d0*a_31*d3*u) + e1*(d0*b_1*u + b_1*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e1*(d2*b_3*u + b_3*d2*u) + e1*(a_13*d2*d1*u + d2*a_13*d1*u) + e1*(a_23*d2*d2*u + d2*a_23*d2*u) + e1*(a_33*d2*d3*u + d2*a_33*d3*u) + e2*(a_00*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d2*a_00*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e2*(a_01*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d3*a_01*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e2*(a_02*(-e2*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) - e3*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + (d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u)*(-e1)) + d0*a_02*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e2*(a_12*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d0*a_12*d1*u) + e2*(a_22*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d0*a_22*d2*u) + e2*(a_32*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d0*a_32*d3*u) + e2*(d0*b_2*u + b_2*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e2*(d2*b_0*u + b_0*d2*u) + e2*(d3*b_1*u + b_1*d3*u) + e2*(a_10*d2*d1*u + d2*a_10*d1*u) + e2*(a_11*d3*d1*u + d3*a_11*d1*u) + e2*(a_20*d2*d2*u + d2*a_20*d2*u) + e2*(a_21*d3*d2*u + d3*a_21*d2*u) + e2*(a_30*d2*d3*u + d2*a_30*d3*u) + e2*(a_31*d3*d3*u + d3*a_31*d3*u) + e3*(a_00*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d3*a_00*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e3*(a_02*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d1*a_02*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e3*(a_03*(-e2*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) - e3*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + (d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u)*(-e1)) + d0*a_03*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e3*(a_13*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d0*a_13*d1*u) + e3*(a_23*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d0*a_23*d2*u) + e3*(a_33*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d0*a_33*d3*u) + e3*(d0*b_3*u + b_3*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u)) + e3*(d1*b_2*u + b_2*d1*u) + e3*(d3*b_0*u + b_0*d3*u) + e3*(a_10*d3*d1*u + d3*a_10*d1*u) + e3*(a_12*d1*d1*u + d1*a_12*d1*u) + e3*(a_20*d3*d2*u + d3*a_20*d2*u) + e3*(a_22*d1*d2*u + d1*a_22*d2*u) + e3*(a_30*d3*d3*u + d3*a_30*d3*u) + e3*(a_32*d1*d3*u + d1*a_32*d3*u) + (a_01*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d1*a_01*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e0) + (a_01*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d2*a_01*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e3) + (a_02*(d2*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d2**2*u - e3*d2*d3*u) + d2*a_02*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e0) + (a_02*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d3*a_02*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e1) + (a_03*(d1*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d1*d2*u - e3*d1*d3*u) + d1*a_03*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e2) + (a_03*(d3*(-e1)*d1*u - e2*d3*d2*u - e3*d3**2*u) + d3*a_03*(d1*(-e1)*u - e2*d2*u - e3*d3*u))*(-e0) + (d1*b_1*u + b_1*d1*u)*(-e0) + (d1*b_3*u + b_3*d1*u)*(-e2) + (d2*b_1*u + b_1*d2*u)*(-e3) + (d2*b_2*u + b_2*d2*u)*(-e0) + (d3*b_2*u + b_2*d3*u)*(-e1) + (d3*b_3*u + b_3*d3*u)*(-e0) + (a_11*d1*d1*u + d1*a_11*d1*u)*(-e0) + (a_11*d2*d1*u + d2*a_11*d1*u)*(-e3) + (a_12*d2*d1*u + d2*a_12*d1*u)*(-e0) + (a_12*d3*d1*u + d3*a_12*d1*u)*(-e1) + (a_13*d1*d1*u + d1*a_13*d1*u)*(-e2) + (a_13*d3*d1*u + d3*a_13*d1*u)*(-e0) + (a_21*d1*d2*u + d1*a_21*d2*u)*(-e0) + (a_21*d2*d2*u + d2*a_21*d2*u)*(-e3) + (a_22*d2*d2*u + d2*a_22*d2*u)*(-e0) + (a_22*d3*d2*u + d3*a_22*d2*u)*(-e1) + (a_23*d1*d2*u + d1*a_23*d2*u)*(-e2) + (a_23*d3*d2*u + d3*a_23*d2*u)*(-e0) + (a_31*d1*d3*u + d1*a_31*d3*u)*(-e0) + (a_31*d2*d3*u + d2*a_31*d3*u)*(-e3) + (a_32*d2*d3*u + d2*a_32*d3*u)*(-e0) + (a_32*d3*d3*u + d3*a_32*d3*u)*(-e1) + (a_33*d1*d3*u + d1*a_33*d3*u)*(-e2) + (a_33*d3*d3*u + d3*a_33*d3*u)*(-e0)
```

Comment: The order / factoring may be different, but that doesn't mean the expression values are. I'm guessing this is the result of a matrix multiplication, and would suggest that you actually use matrices to represent this expression in that case. That would make it easier to verify that the result is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include `B` in your `ns`, so the b symbols were created by sympify automatically as commutative Symbols (you also never defined `e_1` by the way).

I recommend being cleaner with your processes to avoid issues like this:

- Be consistent with `_` vs no `_` before numeric suffixes. Either use a_0 or a0 everywhere.
- Name your variables the same as the symbol names.
- If you have your string at execution time, don't use `sympify`. Rather, just define your symbol names and execute the string as an expression (`expr = e0*((d0*a_00)*(-e1...`). This way, Python will automatically warn you if you have undefined symbol names.
- If you do have to parse strings, you can avoid automatic symbol definition by using `parse_expr`:

  ```
  from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, auto_symbol

  transformations = list(standard_transformations)
  transformations.remove(auto_symbol)

  parse_expr('a*b', local_dict={'a': Symbol('a', commutative=False)}, transformations=transformations)
  ```

  Note how this gives an error about `b` not being defined, rather than just defining it as a commutative Symbol.