# Test the presence of a subexpression involving noncommutative symbols

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following Sympy expression

```
expr=b0*d0*u0 - b0*d1*u1 - b1*d0*u1 - b1*d1*u0 + d0*b0*u0 - d0*b1*u1 - d1*b0*u1 - d1*b1*u0
```

And I want to know if, for example, the product

```
d0*u0
```

is in this expression. For this, I use

```
print(expr.has(d0*u0))
```

but the result is

```
False
```

However, if I replace this subexpression without asking if it is in the expression, Sympy does it without any problem, e.g.

```
print(expr.subs(d0*u0,x0))
b0*x0 - b0*d1*u1 - b1*d0*u1 - b1*d1*u0 + d0*b0*u0 - d0*b1*u1 - d1*b0*u1 - d1*b1*u0
```

So, how can I know if the subexpression I want to find is in the expression?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. `expr.has(d0*u0)` returns `True` for me (SymPy 1.1.1 / Python 3.6.3 / Linux ). Maybe some of the variables is not a `sympy.symbols` ?

Comment: I understand these are noncommutative based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48466845), so edited accordingly.

Comment: The reason `has` didn't find `d0*u0` was a bug which is now [fixed](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/14026) in the development version of SymPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be currently an issue with noncommutative symbols, otherwise `expr.has(d0*u0)` returns True.

The following works whenever `subs` can identify a subexpression:

```
dummy = Dummy()
print(expr.subs(d0*u0, dummy).has(dummy))
```

I.e., replace the subexpression with a dummy variable, and test the presence of that dummy.

However, this workaround will become unnecessary in a future version of SymPy (1.2+) when this bug is fixed.

Comment: One should clarify that this is a workaround. `has` not working is a bug, which is fixed in the development version and should work in the next release (1.2).

Comment: ... which I did [under the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471955/test-the-presence-of-a-subexpression-involving-noncommutative-symbols/48472035?noredirect=1#comment83981448_48471955)